# simpleSAMLphp UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION with testing SP

Tags: php, saml, saml-2.0, service-provider, simplesamlphp

Im not experienced with simpleSAMLphp or SAML in general. I apologize for misconceptions in advance.

I'm seeing following debug information trying to test my SP configuration (to connect to a remote IDP):

```
SimpleSAML\Error\Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
Backtrace:
2 public\_include.php:28 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
1 vendor\symfony\error-handler\ErrorHandler.php:607 (Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler::handleException)
0 [builtin] (N/A)
Caused by: Exception: Unable to send artifact without a datastore configured.
Backtrace:
11 vendor\simplesamlphp\saml2\src\SAML2\HTTPArtifact.php:46 (SAML2\HTTPArtifact::getRedirectURL)
10 vendor\simplesamlphp\saml2\src\SAML2\HTTPArtifact.php:87 (SAML2\HTTPArtifact::send)
9 modules\saml\src\Auth\Source\SP.php:658 (SimpleSAML\Module\saml\Auth\Source\SP::sendSAML2AuthnRequest)
8 modules\saml\src\Auth\Source\SP.php:642 (SimpleSAML\Module\saml\Auth\Source\SP::startSSO2)
7 modules\saml\src\Auth\Source\SP.php:691 (SimpleSAML\Module\saml\Auth\Source\SP::startSSO)
6 modules\saml\src\Auth\Source\SP.php:780 (SimpleSAML\Module\saml\Auth\Source\SP::authenticate)
5 src\SimpleSAML\Auth\Source.php:195 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Source::initLogin)
4 src\SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple.php:170 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple::login)
3 [builtin] (call_user_func_array)
2 src\SimpleSAML\HTTP\RunnableResponse.php:84 (SimpleSAML\HTTP\RunnableResponse::sendContent)
1 vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Response.php:394 (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::send)
0 public\module.php:24 (N/A)
```

I searched for possible solutions to "**Exception: Unable to send artifact without a datastore configured.**" but I couldn't find any. Apache also doesn't provide any error logs.

I am currently using php sessions as datastore.

Is there anything I'm missing? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I switched over to sql as datastore and the error is gone (phpsession as datastore is not insufficient for artifacts).